Is this PFC choke design correct?
I would really appreciate it if you could check this inductor design, if there are any mistakes, or if it can be improved.
I'm designing a \$50\,\mathrm{\mu H}\$ PFC choke for a totem-pole bridgeless PFC. The maximum RMS current at \$60\,\mathrm{Hz}\$ is \$I_{RMS} = 25 \mathrm{A}\$, the switching frequency is \$f_{sw} = 200\,\mathrm{kHz}\$, and the peak-to-peak current ripple at \$f_{sw}\$ is \$I_{pp} = 2.5\,\mathrm{A}\$. This gives a maximum peak current of \$I_{max} = 37\,\mathrm{A}\$.
I'm limited by the total height to 40 mm, so I picked a PQ50/35 core. Given the switching frequency and the permeability stability over temperature, the selected ferrite material is 3C95. These are the effective parameters from the data sheet:

You can find the information for the 3C95 material here (page 5). It says that the initial permeability is around \$\mu_i = 3000\$, and it saturates around \$B = 410\,\mathrm{mT}\$ at \$100\,\mathrm{^\circ C}\$:

With a gap \$g = 2\,\mathrm{mm}\$, we get an \$A_L\$ of:
$$A_L=\frac{\mu_o \mu_i A_e}{l_e+\mu_i g} = 203.85\,\mathrm{nH/turns^2}$$
And we get an inductance of \$L=52.19\,\mathrm{\mu H}\$ with \$N = 16\$ turns (\$L=A_L N^2\$).
To make sure that we don't saturate at \$I_{max}\$, we can calculate \$B_{max}\$:
$$B_{max}=\frac{I_{max}L}{A_e N} = 366.805\,\mathrm{mT} < 410\,\mathrm{mT}$$
To get the estimated core losses at the switching frequency \$f_{sw}\$, we need to calculate \$B_{peak}\$:
$$B_{peak}=\frac{\frac{I_{pp}}{2}L}{A_e N} = 12.39\,\mathrm{mT}$$
Which, from the specific power losses graph, it corresponds to less than \$10\,\mathrm{kW/m^3}\$, giving less than \$0.3\,\mathrm{W}\$ core losses.
Finally, regarding the copper losses, \$16\$ turns with an average radius of \$16 \,\mathrm{mm}\$ give a cable length of \$L_{cable} = 1.6\,\mathrm{m}\$. I will be using Litz wire to reduce the skin effect. An effective cross-section of \$A_{cable} = 4\,\mathrm{mm^2}\$ gives a total resistance \$R\$ for the cable:
$$R=\frac{\rho_{copper} L_{cable}}{A_{cable}} = 7.08\,\mathrm{m\Omega}$$
We can calculate the copper losses as \$P_{copper} = I_{RMS}^2R = 4.38\,\mathrm{W}\$, which is acceptable for my design.
From the core data sheet, the winding window area is \$253.2\,\mathrm{mm^2}\$. Assuming that half of that window is lost in unused space due to the imperfect cable packing, we get around \$8\,\mathrm{mm^2}\$ available per turn. I don't know the difference between the real and effective cross-section for Litz wire, but as long as a Litz wire with an effective cross-section of \$4\,\mathrm{mm^2}\$ does not exceed \$8\,\mathrm{mm^2}\$, everything should fit.

What is input voltage here, like maybe 70Vrms--? Something seems incongruous: one of either Vin, L or Ipp is too small. For example, 50uH, in a 220VAC input PFC, will be more like 11App.

Yes, sorry! I forgot to mention that I will have 2 of these inductors in series. I didn't mention anything about Vin, but I did some simulations taking into account universal input voltage, 400 V DC bus and the PWM modulation that I will be using. The current values from my original post are all accurate and correspond to the worst case scenario.

Your calculations are more or less correct and consistent.
The choice or range of options can be improved, however.
Don't worry about litz: it's not at all needed for such a low ripple fraction.   I calculate 22mW increase for solid over litz, before accounting for proximity effect.  Proximity should increase that by, say, roughly triangularly with the number of layers, but doing this in one or two layers should be reasonable.
More to the point, you'll need some amount of stranding regardless, driven by flexibility and packing -- you're looking at 6AWG equivalent wire here; no way is solid going to happen!  (Edge-wound flat, if you can find a winder that does it, would be an excellent choice however; being self-supported, a bobbin wouldn't be required either, maximizing winding area.)
Area factor for litz is around 0.3.  That's been my experience with round (served) single-build litz.  It can go up to 0.35-0.4 with unserved (sort-of loose strands), and maybe overfilling the bobbin a little bit is acceptable too.
A powder core might be cheaper, or more compact, without much increase in core losses.  Available in larger sizes, and over a modest spread of aspect ratios, you may get better fit using one, than using two PQ's in series.
For example, a High-Flux 60µ core of modest size gives comparable outcome: Magnetics Inc. 0058737A2 looks like 17 turns (59µH nominal) of 7AWG equivalent, gives around 0.8W core loss, 7.5W copper loss, of which 50mW is AC loss (again, ignoring proximity).  Note inductance will come down a little under bias, so going a little high is good.
Alternately, the same size in High-Flux 125µ might use 12 turns (61µH) of 4AWG equivalent, giving 1.7W core and 3.7W copper, or 5.4W total, comparable to your PQ design.
You might well reduce inductance (assuming that's acceptable for control purposes), to increase core loss while reducing DC copper loss more.  For example, if you're going to go to the expense of ferrite and litz, consider 24µH, 11t of 0.1mm dia. x 700 strands litz on a single PQ4030-N97 (not two chokes in series), giving around 4.7W total -- ~half the proposed PQ5030 x 2 solution(!).  This will be BCM to DCM at medium to light load, for which a variable-mode controller will prove advantageous.  Going a little deeper (into current ripple), a QR/BCM controller wouldn't be bad, though you might have to move up to PQ5030 or 35, or 2 x PQ4030 to keep the losses low.  (The high current ripple of QR/BCM or DCM definitely does benefit from litz; especially near the air gap!)
Also, don't miss out on multi-phase interleave, which will save massively on input capacitor/line filter value and ratings, and output capacitor ratings.  It's not clear what total rating you're after, but doing this much power in a single channel would definitely be suboptimal.
Note that these magnetics losses (~5W) are comparable to or smaller than switching losses in SuperJunction MOSFETs, let alone including hard-switched PN junction diodes.  To support comparable efficiency at this frequency, SiC or GaN MOSFETs*, and SiC schottky or synchronous rectification, are required.
*Well, current GaN are HEMT, not a MOS structure, but, to the extent we drive them similarly, anyway.  Incidentally, avoid GaN cascodes: the cascode node capacitance contributes a loss mechanism similar to SJ.
Aside: note that air gap is the calculated value; the physical value will be higher due to fringing.  For example, 2mm calculated, might be more like 3mm here, but the best way is to simply grind a little off and test, and keep going until it's nominal.  To the coil winder, simply specify turns of wire and placement, and the inductance; they'll figure out the gap.

Beware of proximity effect which is the other eddy loss. At lower frequencies like 200 kHz, proximity effect losses will be much higher than skin effect losses.
I quickly whipped up some loss calculations for your winding geometry which shows that a large wire diameter will suffer from extreme ac loss at 200 kHz. This graphical representation is part of my bespoke transformer design kit.

The left panel shows 1-strand of wire where the optimal point where ac loss due to proximity effect and dc loss requires #26 AWG wire. The right panel shows the losses for 100 strands being lowest using #40 AWG wire. The wire can be Litz or bunched conductor - doesn't matter much for reducing proximity effect.
The takeaway from this is large diameter wire suffers from high ac losses due to proximity effect.

Thicker wire gives higher relative AC losses, sure, but what about absolute values -- what's the overall Q factor or loss (W) using realistic wire size? How does that compare to appropriately sized, stranded (>38AWG) litz?

@TimWilliams Lower graphs show ac, dc, and ac+dc losses versus wire diameter for the OP's core size. The panel on the right shows Litz wire, 100 strands #40 AWG. Since the graphs give losses in Ohms, he can figure out the losses from the current passing thru the wires for his waveform.

So you would suggest minimum 16AWG or 100x40AWG for a 25A choke--? Also, I don't see a diagram, or, how much does this vary with turns, turns/layer, layers?

@TimWilliams That's what proximity effect losses say. However, I don't know what sort of waveform is passing thru the choke. The intent is to show that large diameter wire may run in to heating issues if the 200 kHz current is high.

PFC, reasonable to assume square voltage and triangular current; harmonics will be at worst a few percent of total power. Current magnitude is as given, and for voltage, 70-100V per choke is reasonable to assume -- it varies of course with Vin and throughout the cycle, but a ballpark static figure is still a starting point.
